# Copying Variables

Tags: variables, ssis

I am working on SSIS and I have to copy some components from an already existing package of the same project along with the variables created in it. But when I try to copy the component,  the variables are failing to get copied. Is there any way to copy the variables also.

Comment: please show your code so we can contextualize the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, though I had this issue as well and came across this page in my quest. It is only fair to stop on the way back and let you know how I solved it.

I copied and pasted all of my variables (31 of them) in the code section of the package.  Please see the following link for details on how it is done.

http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/05/ssis-how-to-copy-variables-from-ssis.html

Comment: This method copies and the GUID as well and makes it so that I'm unable to open the package without getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy variables. If an object such as a task uses variables, then you must re-create the variables in the destination package. In contrast, if you copy the entire package, then the variables in the package are also copied.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345172.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it's on file system , simply copy the .dtsx files in the Windows itself.
Once you have a copy of the dtsx file, just open it in BIDS as usual - if you want it as part of your solution, just add it as you would any other package.

Please note - The package must be opened in SSIS Designer before the Save As option appears on the File menu.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345176.aspx) is guideline to accomplish same.